# MySQL / SQL Incrementing a Column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

Im trying to keep track of points / stats by making a column auto increment. However, it's not working as I want it. I want it to auto increment if the **row gets updated, not if a new row gets added**. For example, if I run the update command it will just add one to the "count" column for the row I updated. **If I add a new row it'll start at 0!**

**Here is my code to create a table:**

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stats" +
                        "(" +
                        "id varchar(100) not null," +
                        "count int not null auto_increment," +
                        "PRIMARY KEY (id)," +
                        "KEY (count)" +
                        ")"
        );
        statement.execute();
```

**Here is how I update to a specific row:**

```
connection = plugin.getHikari().getConnection();
                statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO stats (id) VALUES(?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=?");
                statement.setString(1, id.toString());
                statement.setString(2, id.toString());
                statement.execute();
```

Thanks,
- Nicster

Comment: You can't select from a table while updating it in the same query, so this might get a bit hairy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute from the `count` column.

AUTO_INCREMENT isn't a suitable mechanism for what you are trying to achieve.

2) Add a DEFAULT 1 to the definition of the `count` column

When a new row is inserted into the table, and a value is not supplied for the `count` column, the default value will be assigned to the column.

3) re-write the INSERT statement to increment the `count` column when an attempt is made to add a duplicate `id` value

```
 INSERT INTO atickets_stats (id)
 VALUES ( ? )
 ON DUPLICATE KEY
 UPDATE count = count + 1 ;
```

Comment: Can you please help in this query, How does it works?

Comment: When the INSERT statement runs, it will attempt to add a new row to the table. If a row already exists in the table that has a `id` value that matches the value supplied for `id` in the INSERT, the INSERT will throw a "duplicate key" exception, due to the PRIMARY KEY (unique constraint) on the `id` column. If that occurs, the ON DUPLICATE KEY portion of the statement is fired. And that performs an operation equivalent to "UPDATE atickets_stats SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = ?". (The row with that specific id value will be updated. The current value of the count column is incremented by 1.

Comment: Reference: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use Before update trigger in this case. Set default value to 1. and update/increment it by 1 on every update using trigger.

Comment: Whatya mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

From mysql doc (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows

So you have to chose a different approach:

1. Read current value from database
2. Prepare your statement updating also the count value

Problem: Concurrency
You have to synchronize your method call to make it thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're having that problem. You're close, IMHO. All you need to do is to make `count` as `INT NOT NULL` default 0. Then you should always do `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` like below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS atickets_stats (
    `id` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `count` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO atickets_stats (id) VALUES(1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

Note, I changed the `count` column to be `INT(11) UNSIGNED` because I assume you won't ever store negative value here. You can take out `UNSIGNED` if you'll have negative value.